# Line has different strokeWidth when placed on a canvas via group

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Why does the following code

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var line = new fabric.Line([100, 50, 100, 100], {
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 1
});
canvas.add(line);

var groupLine = new fabric.Line([100, 50, 100, 100], {});
var group = new fabric.Group([groupLine], {
  top: 50,
  left: 200,
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 1
});
canvas.add(group);
```

results in two lines with different width?

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/pyoq5410/

Both lines have the same `strokeWidth`, the only difference is that one of them is added through a `Group` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that you are applying the stroke to the entire group. Try this:

```
var groupLine = new fabric.Line([150, 50, 150, 100], {
  stroke: 'black', 
  strokeWidth: 1
});
var group = new fabric.Group([groupLine], {});
```

Comment: Sounds still strange that adding strokeWidth on the group does change the line's one, but not to 1.

Comment: Yes, looks like a little bug in Fabric.